# Folhas de estilos (js,css) em subdomínio ou em uma pasta dentro da aplicação?

Tags: php, javascript, css

**Estou com uma dúvida. Acho que alguém já passou por isso algum dia também.**

Sempre carreguei meus estilos dentro de uma pasta em minha aplicação:

```
Ex: http://meudominio.com.br/assets/css - ou js e etc
```

Observando muitos códigos fonte de outros desenvolvedores, 50% utilizam subdomínio:

```
Ex: http://assets.meudominio.com.br/css - ou js e etc
```

Ter algum tipo de subdomínio para estilos aumenta de desempenho em relação ao carregamento da página?

Qual a melhor prática visando o *desempenho*?

Lembrando que utilizo PHP com Codeigniter na maioria de minhas aplicações.
E possuo um cloud server com cpanel. (Se essa informação ajudar..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O subdomínio é a melhor opção para colocar seus arquivos estáticos.

Pois quando o usuário acessar ele irá baixar em paralelo os arquivos do subdomínio. O que deixará mais rápido se comparado a tudo estar sobre o mesmo domínio, onde irá enviar uma requisição, aguardar o retorno, para então começar outra requisição.

Utilizar CDN para seus arquivos também é uma boa opção, por exemplo o jquery, se você usar o jquery https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js e o usuário já tiver acessado algum site, onde utilize esse CDN tambem, ele já terá esse arquivo no cache do browser, e não irá baixar novamente, o que irá fazer o acesso ao seu site mais rápido.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente por motivos de cache e economia de banda.

Pois se você acessar:

1. http://site.com
2. http://site.com

Ao acessar o #1 ele irá carregar os arquivos js, css. Se você acessar o #2 ele irá tentar carregar novamente pois irá achar que é um arquivo diferente.

Já utilizando apenas um sub-domínio tanto faz o endereço do site que você estiver se ele já carregou uma vez ele não irá tentar baixar novamente e irá aproveitar do cache. Por isso o pessoal utiliza CDN, pois diversos sites compartilham o mesmo endereço pra determinado arquivo ex: jQuery.